# React component seems to rerender because of child components (but shouldn't)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, state

I have a page with a tabbed view. If tab 1 is active it should show component A, otherwise component B.

Based on which page/route I come from before, it should default to component B. Both the components don't need props (as they handle data/state internally).

Problem: The parent component renders three times. Because of this, I loose the `state` value from `useLocation` and can't display the second tab. Simplified parent component code:

```
function ContractOverview() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);

  const showBillingCycleTab = location.state?.selectedTab === 'billing-cycles';

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>
        <Trans i18nKey="navigation.billing" />
      </h1>

    {showBillingCycleTab ? <BillingCycleTable /> : <ContractTable />} // if I do it like this, ContractOverview renders three times (and I loose location state)
    {showBillingCycleTab ? <p>component A</p> : <p>component B</p>}  // if I do it like this, ContractOverview renders only once and the location state is correct.
    </Container>
  );
}
```

The route is set up like this:

```
<Route path="/contracts" component={ContractOverview} exact />
```

Screenshot of the `location` logs:
[image: Screenshot that displays three logs instead of one expected]

Usually I'd expect the parent component to only render once as there are no props that could change nor component state that could do something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Couldn't it be routes component or its parent(s) that cause 3 renders?

Comment: @Solo I really can't imagine why. See the portion of my code where I only use paragraph tags (which works as expected). That's why I really do believe that it's a child comp issue.

Comment: Would be tricky to suggest anything unless you post ContractTable and other as well.

Comment: This is not a child issue unless you are changing something in location from there.

I can see that you are using i18n which may lead to one more rerender when you localizaiton file is loaded.

You should post a content of the file, where `<Route path="/contracts" component={ContractOverview} exact />` is placed

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk I removed the i18n line, nothing differently. The `Route` is simply wrapped into a `Switch` nothing else.